# Hadoop: Passwordless SSH error

Tags: hadoop, ssh, permissions, localhost, server

I am trying to enable passwordless ssh for Hadoop 2.6.0 (via Cygwin on Windows 2008 Server). The method I tried is as follows:

```
ssh-keygen -t dsa -P '' -f ~/.ssh/id_dsa
cat ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

I also tried adding the following things to ssh_config file as mentioned in some questions on SO:

```
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys
PermitRootLogin yes
```

Still, I am not able to ssh into the localhost. The output of `ssh -v localhost` is as follows:

```
OpenSSH_6.8p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2a 19 Mar 2015
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to localhost [127.0.0.1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/MP30589/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/MP30589/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/MP30589/.ssh/id_dsa type 2
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/MP30589/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/MP30589/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/MP30589/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/MP30589/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/MP30589/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.8
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.8
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.8 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr umac-64-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr umac-64-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:l/78VMLSVdtD9SMx46+m4NZt4Kmd1x8I038v9ozQYbM
debug1: Host 'localhost' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/MP30589/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/MP30589/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Offering DSA public key: /home/MP30589/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Trying private key: /home/MP30589/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/MP30589/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: password
MP30589@localhost's password:
```

Can anyone please help me out here? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

After you made changes to the SSH server configuration file, you have to force a configuration reload with

```
sudo /etc/init.d/ssh reload
```

Or reboot the system.

Comment: Tried that, but of no help